# How to send header in post request of RestBuilder using grails 3.3.9

Tags: grails, groovy

```
Response response = new RestBuilder.post(finalUrl){
         header: ["ticket", "getProxyTicket()",
                  "name", "abc",
                  "id", "1"
                 ]
        contentType: application/json
        json data
}
```

I have the above code. And when I send the post request through API call, I get an exception "Proxy ticket must be sent as parameter in header". I don't know what is wrong with the code. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set headers in a groovy post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962989/set-headers-in-a-groovy-post-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do it.  This should work:

```
new RestBuilder().post(finalUrl){
     // this will work if you want the value
     // of the ticket header to be the literal "getProxyTicket()".
     // if you are trying to invoke a method and you want the return
     // value of that method to be the header value, remove the double
     // quotes around getProxyTicket()
     header "ticket", "getProxyTicket()"
     header "name", "abc"
     header "id", "1"

    // no need to set the content type, the 
    // json method below will do that
    // contentType: application/json
    json data
}
```